# Updating a column is slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

can someone explain to me why updating a table column is using just one of eight possible processors? I think that such a process could be easily subdivided for all available processors?

The query is just like this:

```
update
    My_Table
set
    column2 = 'Atlantic'
from
    My_Table
where
    column2 != 'Ocean'
```

The table in question is about 6GB. The IO Deltas during the query is about 7MB/s which is quite low.

The server is a remote machine and I'm the only user. Parallelism is enabled.

I'm not using indices which I probably should.

### Update

On solution could be to not to update and to select-into a copy of the table with a case statement. After the copy is done the old table can be deleted. Of course, this is only viable when there is enough disk space.

Comment: Wild guess: Processor affinity has been turned set on the process?

Comment: Do you mean the affinity mask? If so, it's set to 252. The affinity64 mask is 0. I think that's ok?

Comment: Usually DML statements are not parallelised only the where caluse in case of delete/update and select part of insert statements are parallelised.However,Why not add an index to make the query efficient? This will reduce the resource amount used but index usage will depend on the selectivity of column 2 for say <> ocean

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Would I create an index like this: create index Column2_Index on  My_Table(column2)   ? This takes about 6min to create.

Answer (score 0):

My 1st question would be that do you have TRIGGER, as this is generally the min cause.
sice you have such high volume of data, so may like to check on the below points :

index updates
foreign key lookups
foreign key cascades
indexed views
computed columns
check constraints
locks
snapshot isolation
file growth

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't have any triggers, indices, primary or foreign keys, constraints, views, or locks. Just a big table.

Comment: no primary keys and indexes????? your table atleast deserves the right to have a primary key   :)   Can you send the execution plan while executing this update query?

Comment: Better to keep this answer in comment.

Comment: I have put the execution plan xml here: http://pastebin.com/LjHjPtfd Let me know if that's any help.

Comment: it didn't helped except (EstimateRows="74001400"). Although you can give a shot at it by creating primary key for the table and indexes on the foreign keys. It should improve the performace(as i assume you would have already created the index for column2)

Comment: As I said, I don't have primary nor foreign keys. I'm experimenting with clustered indices without much success...

Comment: Nitin, it's just one table that doesn't need to join with any other table.